# How to get date difference and date from the below table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this

| Emplid | REQUEST_ID | Status | Status_Dttm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1 | New | 02-Jun-2022 12.35.00.AM |
| 1231 | 5 | Draft | 02-Jun-2022 12.30.00.AM |
| 1234 | 1 | In Progress | 02-Jun-2022 12.47.00.AM |
| 1234 | 1 | Cancelled | 02-Jun-2022 12.50.00.AM |
| 1234 | 2 | New | 03-Jun-2022 12.47.00.AM |

Trying to create a view with the fields as `EMPLID`,`REQUEST_ID`,`REQUEST_DATE`,`NO_OF_DAYS_IN_NEW`,`IN_PROGRESS_SINCE`,`COMPLETED/CANCELLED DATE`
Tried using this

```
SELECT MIN(emplid) AS emplid, request_id, MIN(status_dttm) AS request_date, 
       MAX(status) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY status_dttm) AS current_status 
  FROM sts_tbl 
 GROUP BY request_id 
          CASE WHEN (MAX(status) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY status_dttm)) = 'NEW' THEN 
                     TRUNC(SYSDATE) - MIN(status_dttm) 
                END AS "No of Days in New"
          CASE WHEN (MAX(status) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY status_dttm)) = 'In Progree' THEN 
                     status_dttm 
                END AS "In Progress Since" 
  FROM sts_tbl 
 GROUP BY emplid,request_id
```

getting error as "Not a Group By expression"

Comment: All mixed up all :) I've just reformatted, please examine again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LEAD` analytic function to find the time of the next status change and then aggregate:

```sql
SELECT MIN(emplid) AS emplid,
       request_id,
       MIN(status_dttm) AS request_date,
       SUM(CASE status WHEN 'New' THEN duration ELSE 0 END) AS no_of_days_in_new,
       MIN(CASE status WHEN 'In Progress' THEN status_dttm END)
         AS in_progress_since,
       MAX(status) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY status_dttm)
         AS current_status,
       MIN(CASE WHEN status IN ('Completed', 'Cancelled') THEN status_dttm END)
         AS completed_cancelled_date
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         LEAD(status_dttm, 1, SYSDATE) OVER (
           PARTITION BY request_id ORDER BY status_dttm
         ) - status_dttm AS duration
  FROM   sts_tbl t
)
GROUP BY request_id
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE sts_tbl (Emplid, REQUEST_ID, Status, Status_Dttm) AS
SELECT 1234, 1, 'Open',        DATE '2022-06-02' + INTERVAL '35' MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1231, 5, 'Draft',       DATE '2022-06-02' + INTERVAL '30' MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, 1, 'In Progress', DATE '2022-06-02' + INTERVAL '47' MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, 1, 'Cancelled',   DATE '2022-06-02' + INTERVAL '50' MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, 2, 'New',         DATE '2022-06-03' + INTERVAL '47' MINUTE FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | EMPLID | REQUEST_ID | REQUEST_DATE | NO_OF_DAYS_IN_NEW | IN_PROGRESS_SINCE | CURRENT_STATUS | COMPLETED_CANCELLED_DATE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1234 | 1 | 2022-06-02 00:35:00 | 0 | 2022-06-02 00:47:00 | Cancelled | 2022-06-02 00:50:00 |
> | 1234 | 2 | 2022-06-03 00:47:00 | 80.54319444444444444444444444444444444444 | *null* | New | *null* |
> | 1231 | 5 | 2022-06-02 00:30:00 | 0 | *null* | Draft | *null* |

*Note: there is not a next status for `request_id` `2` so it is assumed that the number of days in the New status is from the start of the new status until the current date.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=48f0877e30ee971d05b80dabe3798303)*

Comment: I tried your solution, but I'm getting error as `ORA-00932: inconsistent Datatypes: expected INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND got NUMBER` in my table Status_Dttm is `TIMESTAMP(6)`

Comment: @ajax Then `CAST` the timestamps to a date before calculating the difference [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b164ae532a5fbf894681da4772876335). (And make sure your question contains all the relevant information.)

Comment: thank you its working as expected... can we round off NO_OF_DAYS_IN_NEW column so it does not shows any decimal values and for the columns showing date like IN_PROGRESS_SINCE or COMPLETED_CANCELLED_DATE to convert it as DD-Mon-YYY format?

Comment: @ajax Use `TRUNC` or `FLOOR` for rounding down and `TO_CHAR` for formatting dates.